# Python TCP Server blocks forever in send to client if client is stopped (SIGSTOP)

Tags: python, linux, sockets, tcp

I have an extremely simple tcp server in python the code for which is below:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           

import socket

sock = socket.socket()

sock.bind(('',3912))
sock.listen(100)

num_cons = 10
cons = []
for i in range(num_cons):
    con, addr = sock.accept()
    cons.append(con)

while True:
    for con in cons:
        msg = "a"* 1000
        num_sent = con.send(msg.encode())
        print("sent: {} bytes of msg:{}".format(str(num_sent), msg))
```

The corresponding client code is

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                           

import socket

sock = socket.socket()

sock.connect(('',3912)) # in reality here I use the IP of the host where 
# I run the server since I launch the clients on a different host

while True:
    data = sock.recv(1000)
    print("received data: {} ".format(str(data)))
```

Now, if  I start the server with

```sh
./server.py
```

and 10 clients in parallel from a **different** host:

```sh
for i in `seq 1 10`; do ./client.py 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null & done
```

And I send `kill -SIGSTOP %1` to the first client, I expect the server to successfully keep trying to send data because it cannot know that the client has been stopped. Instead, the server blocks when it tries to send the data to client 1. I can understand the behaviour if the clients were on the same host as the server: we tried to write data, but the kernel buffers are full, so we block in the server, but the client never reads, so the buffer is never freed. However, if the clients are on a different machine, the kernel buffers of the server host should only be full temporarily and then the kernel should send the data over the network card and free them. So why is my server blocking on the `send` call? I have not verified if the same behaviour is seen when using a different language (C for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is weird because 1000 characters is a small size for TCP. I have no available Linux machine but on a FreeBSD box, I could successfully send 130000 bytes on a TCP connection where the peer was stopped before the sender blocks. And more that 1000000 on Windows.

But as TCP is a connected protocol, a `send` call will block if it cannot queue its data because the internal TCP stack queue is full.

Answer (score -1):

The gist of your problem seems to be that you're creating a SOCK_STREAM socket (i.e. TCP), and then abruptly terminating the client. As discussed in the Python [Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#when-sockets-die), a hang is expected in this situation.

TCP is a [reliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliability_(computer_networking)) protocol, meaning that every transmitted packet has to be acked. If the receiving side is dead, the sender will block waiting for that acknowledgement. Try setting a timeout and see if your `send` raises a `socket.timeout` after the expected time.

Comment: They're not terminating the client, they are stopping it, which can be reversed using `kill -SIGCONT %1`. If the receiving side was terminated, the TCP stack would close the connection of which the sending side is notified. BTW: An alternative approach is to use non-blocking sockets or a `select()`-based approach, where you only send data when the socket can actually process it.

Comment: I am not terminating the client, I am stopping it.